# Monitor goes sleep during fullscreen black scene

Tags: suspend, monitor, external-monitor

My monitor (Samsung SyncMaster 171s) turns into sleep mode for few seconds when there is totally black scene in fullscreen (for example: between two scenes in a movie). How can I disable it?

I'm using Asus eee 1000h with Ubuntu 14.04. Have the same problrm, when monitor is plugged in into Dell Optiplex GX620 with Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon.

Comment: What about in Windows, does the same happen?

Comment: No. In Windows it was ok.